# Order by different Enum property each row

Tags: c#, algorithms, order

So I have a list of DefaultSearchModal items that have an enum called TypeSearch in every list item. I would like to order the list to have a different enum property each row.

So if you have an unordered list by this:

1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5

I would like to order it to:

1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5

What would be a good algorithm to sort it like this?

```
    public class DefaultSearchModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public TypeSearch TypeSearch { get; set; }
}

public enum TypeSearch
        {
           News = 0,
           Blog = 1,
           Photo = 3,
           Page = 4
        }
```

Comment: You've provided plenty of information for someone to come up with a solution, but you should also make an attempt at it yourself and share the code.

Comment: You just want to order by TypeSearch, but can't have consecutive enums if possible?  I guess I'm not sure what the significance of your specific order means, that could help in defining a way to make it happen.

Comment: @bowlturner This is ment for a website search. So i need to display different found items. I want to avoid that you first see 5 pages of news articles and then the other found stuff.

Comment: @Jamie: What have you tried so far? Any code to show, even if it doesn't quite work the way you want?

Comment: OK so there is no connection between 1,2,3,4,5 just take the first of each available then the next etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would just put it in a loop Here's psudo code for it.

```
while mainList has items
{
  find first 0 item.
  add to queue, 
  remove from mailList

  find first 1 item 
  add to queue, 
  remove from mailList

  find first 3 item.
  add to queue, 
  remove from mailList

  find first 4 item.
  add to queue, 
  remove from mailList
}

return queue
```

Comment: Great idea to remove the found item from the list and keep going till there are no more items left. I was way overthinking this. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

The end result thanks to bowlturner:

```
  private IEnumerable<DefaultSearchModel> Sort(IList<DefaultSearchModel> items)
    {
        var returnList = new Collection<DefaultSearchModel>();

        while (items.Any())
        {
            foreach (var type in Enum.GetValues(typeof (TypeSearch)))
            {
                if (items.Any(x => x.TypeSearch == (TypeSearch) type))
                {
                    var item = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TypeSearch == (TypeSearch) type);
                    returnList.Add(item);
                    items.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

Comment: This is a bit inefficient. Eg. after `.Any(x => x.TypeSearch == (TypeSearch) type)` you're calling `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TypeSearch == (TypeSearch) type)`, which searches for the same matching item once again. And why `OrDefault` (instead of simply `First`), given that you've only just confirmed there *must* be at least one item that matches the criteria?? You could have skipped `Any`, use `FirstOrDefault` only and just give up if it returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

My FP-flavored solution:

```
IEnumerable<DefaultSearchModel> DoMagic(IEnumerable<DefaultSearchModel> models)
{
    var groups = models.GroupBy(model => model.TypeSearch);
    var solution = Enumerable
        .Range(0, groups.Max(grp => grp.Count()))
        .SelectMany(i => groups
            .Where(grp => grp.Count() > i)
            .Select(grp => grp.ElementAt(i))
            .OrderBy(model => model.TypeSearch));
    return solution;
}
```

Probably not most efficient either (since I pointed out that @Jamie's solution isn't, I can't be a hypocrite), but it is not my point right now. I just wanted to show how terse and non-imperative LINQ can be.

Note that we are *not* repeatedly looking for `TypeSearch` values that aren't on the list at all, or whose count is beyond a specific treshold.

Comment: Not the most readable either... :-)

Comment: @fishinear surely it takes a while to learn to parse it. But once you get used to the paradigm, it isn't so difficult. I find SQL unreadable every time I haven't had worked with raw SQL for a while :) Note that you can always break a complex expression down into a few helpfully named local variables. One significant advantage of using, say, ready-made `GroupBy` instead of implementing it by yourself "manually" is that `GroupBy` has already been tested a zilion times and it's very unlikely that there are any bugs in it. The same cannot be said about our implementation, custom-written ad hoc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go once through the list and divide them up in 5 sets.
2. Then simply take one object (if available) from each set in order, and put them into
   your output list
3. Repeat step 2 until all sets are empty

Algorithm has O(n)